# Add header to existing PDF (template)

Tags: html, itext

I´m using itext v5.x.
I have a pdf document, which is being used as a template.
Users can define their own headers and footers by using images (scaled to the correct width of the page size - A4, but with an flexible height).

I now want to create a new pdf document by importing the template and adding a header and footer using the user defined images.

I got this basically working using a pdfReader and pdfWriter. I import the pages from the template (source file) and add them as a template page. The header and footer are being created using the page events.

My problem is, that depending on the height of the footer or header the page content overlaps the footer. There seems to be no automatic page break.

The code looks like this (pseudo):

```cs
using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Server.MapPath("~/App_files/xxx.pdf")))
{
    using (var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 36f, 36f, 115,115))
    {
        using (var workStream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/App_files/Downloads/xxx2.pdf"), FileMode.Create))
        {

            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, workStream);
            writer.CloseStream = false;
            writer.PageEvent = pageEventHelper;

            document.Open();

            PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
            PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);

            cb.AddTemplate(page,0,0);
            page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 2);
            document.NewPage();
            cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
            document.Close();

        }
    }
    reader.Close();
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

All the best...
Florian

Comment: *"There seems to be no automatic page break."* - Correct, there is none. Each page is a canvas in its own right onto which you can add templates at arbitrary positions which then may or may not overlap depending on the contents and positions of the templates. If you expect the contents of such overlapping regions somehow magically to be reflowed: This does not happen.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the info.